# Models that are good for long answer generation given context and question and what datasets would be the best for training?

Tags: nlp, data, model-selection, text-generation, question-answering

Basically I am trying to create a context-needing question and long answer model and I was wondering what model would be best for such tasks, currently I am leaning towards T5, or GPT-NeoX-20B. Additionally for such tasks what datasets would be the most suitable, as of right now I have looked at CoQA, and SQuAD but none provide long answers.

Comment: How many words or characters has a long answer? GPT has a function min_lenght and max_lenght when you apply model.generate(...). So basically it can have any length.

Comment: I see, that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comment from Nicolas Martin, I found [gpt2 for qa pair generation](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/gpt2-for-qa-pair-generation/759/4) which gave reasonable steps on how to utilize Question and Answering for GPT models and then I can specify min_length and max_length to create a long answer.